# What should I know , to use a certain pentatonic over a backtrack loop?

Tags: electric-guitar

Well I'm playing eletric guitar for a lot of years, but I just didnt care about theory. I just love to play acdc, airbourne, and etc...but now the time has come, and I would love to create my own simple backtracks and start soloing. I'm doing some classes but for now I have what I think is a simple question.

let's say I created a simple backtrack with f - g - A (simple power chords).

It keeps this forever, since I'm just trying to solo with pentatonics.

How can I know, what tone is this backtrack, to use the correct pentatonic scale?

Should I use this harmonic field map, and track what note has f - g - A ?

it's really simple, I just would like to know how to create a backtrack, kwoing what tone it is, to use a simple pentatonic. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just F G and A in the looper, and 5s at that, there's no major or minor to consider. However, pretending that the chords were Fmaj., Gmaj. and Am, then Am pent. would work quite well, given that all three are within the C diatonic notes. Making C major pent. work just as well - mainly because both pents have exactly the same notes!

Obviously, one or two of the notes fit better (or worse) over each 'chord', but that's where the old ears come in quite useful.

Comment: Ohh thank you. I thougnt I could fit any chords togheter to create a simple loop. Thanks. with this simple question, I could clear my mind hahaha

Comment: And Just one more question. Why I can fit a Aminor pentatonic over  a `A - G - F` loop? ( stairway to heaven's  solo ). It's because Cmajor is the same as Aminor, and these notes can be found on C major tone? The famous "relative minior"?

Comment: Yes, relatives they are! Bit like my Aunty... And Stairway *is* in Am. There's usually more scope for improve. when chords are at least maj. or min. 7ths give even more!

Comment: You can use Am pentatonic of course, but if you end up adding a 6th note (usually a F# in key of Am), try flattening it to an F. I guess this is using a Aeolian mode ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_(music)#Aeolian_(VI)  ). It's similar to the solo in Dire Straits' Sultans of Swing: same relative chords as yours, but in Dm instead.  Basically in Am, instead of playing a F# 6th, try playing an F 6th, to accommodate the F chord in your sequence.

Comment: @user2808054 - the sixth note in A minor can be *either* F *or*  F#. But at that point, it's no longer pentatonic! And in actual fact, any of the 12 notes *can* be used, and *will* fit, if used properly. But that's not the OP's point.

Comment: @Tim   I agree with everything you've said. 'Twas just a suggestion (hence a comment, not an answer)